# http sampler modifies the parameter before sending it?

Tags: http, jmeter

I have a http sampler with a `parameter name: course_title` and `parameter value: Art&DesignBTECLevel2Diploma`

Parameters
[image]

Request part of View Result Tree
[image]

When I run this sampler, the parameter that JMeter sends in request is Art. I came across this in the request section of View Result Tree.
My finding or understanding is that the value after "&" character just gets ignored or eliminated by JMeter.

Has any one come across with this issue? How can I resolve this?

I have also tried replacing the "&" with %26 and uncheck the Encode but still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the View Result Tree: In the "HTTP" Tab, the suffix is not shown, but if you switch to the "Raw" tab, it shows the correct request, **including** the part after the ampersand. (Tested with JMeter 2.9)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is showing in "Raw" tab. 
But I am not sure which value is exactly passing to the server "Art&DesignBTECLevel2Diploma" or "Art" because it is not able to submit the form, So, I guess "Art" is passing.